# When graduated and thinking hard problems by own, how to get help on hard parts?

Tags: mathematics, learning

I graduated from maths with better than average grades. But on my free time I would like to learn a book Qing Liu: Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves on my own. The problem is that it has some really difficult problems I can't do. I asked the author of the book a hint for a particular problem but he was not willing to help in doing that problem. Here is an example problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150852/complete-ring-and-unique-continuous-homomorphism

What would be the best way to learn to do difficult problems on my own or get some personal guide to help me through the hard parts? Should I hire a personal teacher or what?

Comment: "I asked the author of the book a hint for a particular problem but he was not willing to help."  This leaves a bit of a bad taste in my mouth.  Qing Liu helped everyone in the world who is interested in arithmetic geometry by writing such a wonderful text on it: one can only imagine how many hundreds of hours of (not specifically paid or rewarded) work this must have taken.  Calling out the author of a text for not being willing to answer individual questions about how to do exercises from the text seems ungracious to me.

Comment: Study pre-requisite courses, study same or easier level books which have solved problems, study the book you want to learn, think about the hard problems for some time, study the guide books to the problems of the book you are mentioning (if exists) and finally, if you have some questions; ask from a friend, a PhD level student or a professor who has time to help you. This is how I used to study my courses for my BSc and MSc degrees and how I self study the scientific books I like after I graduated.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark It is true what you wrote. I meant that he didn't helped me in that problem but of course it is a good that there is such a book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'll pardon me, I suspect that you are accidentally under-prepared for that particular book, as well-written as it is. That is, in U.S. terms, it'd presume a *sophistication* at second- or third-year graduate level, and would be challenging at that point. I think the very context of it would be incomprehensible, misunderstood, unfathomable, to even a fairly good U.S. bachelor's-degree student in the U.S. It's not that it's "difficult", but that it implicitly refers to many (yes, standard, but, ...) ideas without letting on where to follow up, nor letting on that there is non-trivial work to be done in doing that set-up.

Indeed, you might be hard-pressed (depending where you are in the world) to find a "tutor" who could parse the material well enough to explain it to you. Again, not that it's "hard", but that its context is *sophisticated*.

So I really should recommend some suitable prior reading, but I'm a bit out of touch with contemporary sources in this direction, so hopefully someone else can give pointers. One classic would be Atiyah-MacDonald, despite the fact that much of the work there is left to the reader. Still, it does implicitly admit that there is some work to do to have in hand a certain repertoire of riffs that Q. Liu's book may take for granted.